# Android - Context is null when using AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, alert, fragment

**EDIT**

Unfortunately none of the answers provided worked but I did find a way to fix my problem. Instead of using the onCreateDialog method I created my own method which took context as a parameter and made the alertDialog in there. This may not be the most ideal solution but it's good enough for what I need. I will fix it up more and change it in the future. Here is what I did.

Dialog class:

```
public class SaveDialog extends FragmentActivity {


PasswordGen pG = new PasswordGen();


public Dialog createDialog(Context mContext) {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

builder.setTitle("ok");
builder.setMessage("ok")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
return dialog;
```

MainActivity: This is where I call the alertDialog:

```
    private void savePassword() {

    SaveDialog sD = new SaveDialog();


    sD.createDialog(mContext);


    }
```

I'm trying to set up an AlertDialog which is set up in another class. However when I pass the context from the main activity to the AlertDialog class I get a **NullPointerException**

This is my Alert Dialog class

```
public class SaveDialog extends DialogFragment {

Context mContext;

public SaveDialog() {

}

public  SaveDialog(Context mContext) {

    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);



    builder.setTitle("Save Password");
    builder.setView(getContentView());
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
//  dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

and this is where the onClick is launched:

```
private void savePassword() {

    mContext = PasswordGen.this;    

    SaveDialog savePasswordDialog = new SaveDialog(mContext);
    savePasswordDialog.show(savePasswordDialog.getFragmentManager(), "password");

    }
```

I am desperate for answers. I have tried everything from getApplicationContext() to getActivity() to ActivityName.this and I always get a NullPointerException. I even set up a method to check if mContext is null and it comes back as not null, yet the application still crashes.

Comment: where is `getContentView()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating an `AlertDialog`, you're creating a `DialogFragment`. The lifecycle for this is quite different. When the Android system creates your fragment, it's not going through the `SaveDialog(Context mContext)` constructor, it goes through the default constructor, hence the `NullPointerException`. Remove that constructor, it does nothing for you.

You can get the context for the `DialogFragment` like so:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Save Password");
    builder.setView(getContentView());
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, when you create the `AlertDialog` with its `Builder`, you are using a `mContext` variable that is initialized to null.

Yo must override the `DialogFragment onCreate` function to get the right `Context` and then initialize your `mContext` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

See if that works? Unless you have to pass mContext for whatever reason. But from what I can see mContext is not being set and remaining null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the empty constructor:

```
public SaveDialog() {
}
```

and keep only the second constructor when you initialize mContext.

Comment: I thought he might create a dialog without passing a context to its constructor then the first constructor would be used and the context is null at this case. But he said he is passing the context. I'll remove this answer